# iterate over zip iterable to produce multiple rows in table - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html-table

I have a database of arrays that I want to unpack and insert into a table.

For example I'll have an array called `a=[1,2,3,4]` and `b=['a','b','c','d']` each with and equal length.

And I will have a table with just the headers

| a | b |
| --- | --- |

My generated array would be
`[[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c'],[4,'d']]` created with the zip function from the `underscore` package.

My goal is to iterate over this array and generate the following

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'a' |
| 2 | 'b' |
| 3 | 'c' |
| 4 | 'd' |

At the moment, I have a

```js
function returnIt(){
        let _ = require('underscore')
        //returns [[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c'],[4,'d']] so x[0] = 1 and x[1] = 'a'
        for (var x of _.zip([1,2,3,4],['a','b','c','d'])){
            return (
                <>
                    <td>
                        {x[0]}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {x[1]}
                    </td>
                </>
            )
        }
return(
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>a</th>
                <th>b</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                {returnIt()}
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
)
```

But this doesn't work. I get

---

[image]

As you can see I only get one row, the code does not produce more than one row! Sorry about the headers, I tried changing my program as much as I could to suit your eyes.

Anyways, how come this is my result and what can I change?

Comment: `<tr><div><td></td><td></td></div></tr>` is invalid markup (and most likely the source of the output)

Comment: @Andreas Yes, it is the source of one problem, the spacing. But still I am only able to produce one row.

Comment: Hint: `return` does what?

Comment: @Andreas returns a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `returnIt`, your for loop returns in the code block so it will only run once and return the first pair of array elements you've transformed to html elements. Try returning a *mapping* of the zipped elements to markup fragments.  Then you’ll see them all.

Here's a complete example:

```
import _ from "underscore";

export default function App() {
 
  return(
  <table>
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>a</th>
              <th>b</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          
              {returnIt()}

      </tbody>
  </table>)

}

function returnIt(){
  //returns [[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c'],[4,'d']] so x[0] = 1 and x[1] = 'a'
  let zipped = _.zip([1,2,3,4],['a','b','c','d'])
  return zipped.map(pair => {
      return (
          <tr>
              <td>
                  {pair[0]}
              </td>
              <td>
                  {pair[1]}
              </td>
          </tr>
      )
  })
}
```

Comment: Ok I understand a lot better now. Problem is that, It never goes to the next row.

Comment: Great! I did not think of this!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is using React

```
return (
                <>
                    <td>
                        {x[0]}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {x[1]}
                    </td>
                </>
            )
```

`<td>` should be direct descendant of `<tr>`

Comment: sorrry, forgot to add that tag. Also this worked, but sadly it does not fix my single row problem.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you're returning from the loop body. So it'll only ever get to the first element.

```
for (anything) {
   return ...
}
```

will always return immediately without continuing the loop, no matter what is between the parentheses.

You need to have the loop build up the HTML and return all the rows at once, or else maybe use something like a generator function and add a loop to the place that *calls* the function.

Assuming you're using some framework that lets you just `return` unquoted HTML like that, the problem with the table part of your return value is probably that you can't have a `<div>` between a `<tr>` and one of its enclosed `<td>`s.

Comment: Is this really worth an answer? And why not just a close-vote?